# XML children with parameters import

Tags: ee2, solspace, import, xml, solspace-importer

I'm using **Solspace Importer** to create channel entries from external **XML**.

It works fine but only with first title/description element (*lang="**es**"*). How can I grab data from (*lang="**en**"*) children?

My XML structure is below & full huge file is [here](http://www.elenahills.com/exportacion/export.xml).

```
<root>
    <property>
        <descriptions>
            <title lang="es">
                <![CDATA[ Bungalow en Altea Hills ]]>
            </title>
            <title lang="en">
                <![CDATA[ Bungalow in Altea Hills ]]>
            </title>
            <description lang="es">
                <![CDATA[
                    Bonito bungalo en Altea Hills con vistas al mar.
                ]]>
            </description>
            <description lang="en">
                <![CDATA[
                    Lovely bungalow in Altea Hills with sea view.
                ]]>
            </description>
        </descriptions>
    </property>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, Importer does not read XML node attributes, such as lang="es" for example. Therefore, Importer will read only the first node of a series of nodes named exactly the same, `<description>` in this case.

I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

A workaround would be to use different node names for "en" and "es" nodes. For example:

```
<description_es>... data ...</description_en>
<description_en>... data ...</description_en>
```